# Recovery Symfony2 session

Tags: php, symfony

I am a beginner in PHP and am working on a web application developed in Symfony 2, in this application I built a flash module that records the sound of the microphone and save the mp3 file to the connected account folder.
(each user must be connected for it to make recording)
here is my code which is used to save the mp3 file to a folder (recording / user1)

```
<?php
$songname = $_GET["name"];
$filename = $songname. " - " . date("dmY"). ".mp3";
$file = "recording/" . $filename;
$songname $_GET["name"];
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
$fp = fopen($file, "w");

while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);

echo $filename;
}
?>
```

My question: If possible, please retrieve the session or the name and user name connected and send the mp3 file directly to each user's folder (folders are created in advance in the recording folder).
thank you

Comment: You should post your Controller source code ...